How do I write a rasterfile combined with a Style using Jiffle
if I e.g. set value 0.5 for the red band in a style for a rgb raster file like this:
ContrastEnhancement ce1 = sf.contrastEnhancement(ff.literal(0.5), ContrastMethod.NORMALIZE);
sct[0] = sf.createSelectedChannelType(String.valueOf(channelNum[0]), ce1);

I'm satisfied with this value (0.5) and now I would like to save this change in a new tif-file.
I really don't know what I'm doing here:
sf.contrastEnhancement(ff.literal(0.5)...

I'm trying to use Jiffle for this, but I dont know how to do it.
I've tried this:
inCov = reader.read(null);
Process jiffle = (Process) Processors.createProcess(new NameImpl("ras", "Jiffle"));
Map<String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<>();
inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_SOURCE_NAME, new String[] {"a"});
inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_COVERAGE, new GridCoverage2D[] {inCov});
String scr;
scr="dest[0]=a[0] + a[0]*0.5;";
// scr="dest[0]=a[0]?????
inputs.put(JiffleProcess.IN_SCRIPT, scr);
Map<String, Object> output = ((org.geotools.process.Process) jiffle).execute(inputs, null);

But the result is not close to the viewed raster with the modified style.
How can I define "dest[0]=..." to get a raster file to look like the original file with the updated Style?

I think normalize does a stretch as well, but it's been a while since I wrote that code so I can't swear to it.

So, if I have done this to the Style: ContrastEnhancement ce1 = sf.contrastEnhancement(ff.literal(0.5),  ContrastMethod.NORMALIZE);
sct[0] = sf.createSelectedChannelType(String.valueOf(channelNum[0]), ce1);   How do I later implement the change in the new Tiff file (scr = "dest[0] = ????")

After a bit of digging I found the code for the ContrastEnhancement process  in ContrastEnhancementType, and its basically this:
        NoDataContainer destinationNoData = getDestinationNoData(inputWorker);
        double offsetAdjustment = destinationNoData == null ? 0 : 1;
        // compute the scale factors
        final double delta = extrema[1][0] - extrema[0][0];
        final double scale = (maximum - minimum - offsetAdjustment) / delta;
        final double offset = minimum - scale * extrema[0][0] + offsetAdjustment;

So assuming that you have no NoData pixels you should be able to replicate this in Jiffle as (though I haven't actually tested this):
delta = range(src[0]);
minimum = min(src[0]);
maximum = max(src[0]);
scale = (maximum - minimum)/delta;
offset = (minimum - scale * maximum);
dest[0] = src[0] * scale + offset;


I don't really understand this, where is Style information in the example  above? Isn't src the original image that combined with a Style changes the look of the red band?

there is no style involved - the style will only work on a renderedImage while you want to change the actual data values

In my rendered image I read max=255, min=1 (via ImageWorker) and I assume delta=255?? (dont know how to get it from the rendered image) then scale=0.996 and offset = -253, which results in an image with R=0.
